# codeigniter upload images from different inputs

Tags: codeigniter, upload, image-upload

my code is working fine in the single upload, but I want to make a loop for my code that I won't repeatedly create a function over and over because of using two different inputs.

```
public function uploadImage_1()
{       
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '2608';
    $config['max_width'] = '2608';
    $config['max_height'] = '2608';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile1')){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }else{
        $fileName = $this->upload->data();
        $post_image = $fileName['file_name'];
        return $post_image;
    }
}

public function uploadImage_2()
{}
```

`  **View**

```
<input type="file" name="userfile1" size="20" required/>
<input type="file" name="userfile2" size="20" required/>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the input field name as parameter into your function.

**like this:**

```
public function uploadImage($input_field_name)
{       
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '2608';
    $config['max_width'] = '2608';
    $config['max_height'] = '2608';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( !$this->upload->do_upload($input_field_name)){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }else{
        $fileName = $this->upload->data();
        $post_image = $fileName['file_name'];
        return $post_image;
    }
}
```

Now use the above function like this:

```
// These variables stores the name of your files
$fileName_1 = $this->uploadImage('userfile1');
$fileName_2 = $this->uploadImage('userfile2');
```

Comment: what if i would like to store the $fileName_1 into an array. like those?                    
  '$data = array(                                                                                                                 
                  'UserFile' => $this->uploadImage(),
    'UserFile1'  => $this->uploadImage_2()
    );'

Comment: @HanthonyTagam You can use something like this: $data = array(
    'UserFile1' => $this->uploadImage('userfile1'),
    'UserFile2' => $this->uploadImage('userfile2')
);

Comment: already did that earlier and it just show me two equivalent results

Comment: @HanthonyTagam after the above array use this code and show me what you get as output: var_dump($data);

Comment: array(3) { ["userId"]=> string(2) "31" ["UserFile"]=> string(28) "Avengers-Giant-Man-ico44.png" ["UserFile1"]=> string(28) "Avengers-Giant-Man-ico45.png" }

Comment: Id is 31, first userfile is avengers-giant, second userfile is avengers-hulk

Comment: @HanthonyTagam Ok. So, what's wrong in the answer? First file name is "Avengers-Giant-Man-ico44.png" and second one is "Avengers-Giant-Man-ico45.png". Both files name are different.

Comment: no i saved different images which the first one is Giant-Man and the second is Hulk. now Avengers-Giant-Man-ico45 and Avengers-Giant-Man-ico44.png when image is retrieve it shows the same image